# Block other users on GitHub from editing my repos without paying for private repos

Tags: github

When using GitHub to host a repository, can I use it for free (without having to pay for private repos), yet protect my work so others cannot edit it?

Can I essentially have it read-only?

Comment: This is how it works by default.  You have to explicitly allow other people to edit your code.  They can always make a copy (fork) and edit the copy (fork).

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Off topic - About avoiding having to pay for use of the SaaS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On GitHub, others **cannot** edit your work, they can copy it (clone or fork) and then send it back to you - it's then your job to accept the code they submit and only if you want to.

If you wish to hide what you are doing, *aka* have a private repository (still for free), may I suggest using [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) or [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/).

For good tutorials and ressources for Git and GitHub, I'd suggest the following:

- The [Pro-Git book](http://git-scm.com/book) by Scott Chacon available on the git website.
- The [Try Git website available on GitHub made by CodeSchool](http://try.github.io/)
- Or you can try the [Git Immersion](http://gitimmersion.com/)
- If you're still hungry after this, there is a [good list of other git stuff here](http://sixrevisions.com/resources/git-tutorials-beginners/).

Have a great time learning Git ;)

Comment: From looking at it, am I right in saying I can use Git along with Bitbucket? Which would you recommend github or the bitbucket?

Comment: Yes, BitBucket allows Git too. It works the same as GitHub. In fact, I use both ! I use Bitbucket for private stuff and Github for public projects. That way, you have both goodies.

Comment: It's been a few years since this answer was posted... Now GitHub allows for private and public repositories for free anyway. You may still need to choose if you want to collaborate on private repositories (paid feature on GitHub)

Answer (score 4):

Nobody can directly *edit* your work on Github, though they can **[fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo)** your public repos and make changes (to your code) there.

The only way their edits will appear in your code is if you accept the **[pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests)** from the fork.

Resources:

- [Github Help](https://help.github.com/)
- [Git SCM](http://git-scm.com/)

Comment: It's been a few years since this answer was posted. I don't think it's true today. Now GitHub allows  – to contribute, to directly push any changes to public repositories, without any forks and pull requests. Looking for a way to make my repo public for reading, but private for writting , and can not find how to configure it.